# Getting Android drivers to work on Windows 8 Community Preview

Tags: drivers, windows-8-preview, android

I made [a post about this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/21244/motorola-usb-drivers-on-windows-8) on android.stackexchange.com, and they referred me to here.

I have an HTC Flyer and a Motorola Droid X, and for both, I've been unable to connect to USB debugging to do Android development.

With the Motorola Droid X, the MotoHelper installer won't run, saying that I'm running an Unknown OS Version.

With the HTC Flyer, HTC's Sync software installs successfully, but again the device doesn't connect.

I realize that this is beta software, but is there anything that I can do to get this working? I've been relying on switching back to my laptop running Linux to test out my Android builds on the device. Of course, I'm not in any production environment - just playing around with the new OS, but not being able to write code on it makes less fun.